# How do I loop through all levels of a data structure to extract all data when I don't know how many levels there will be?

Tags: python, xml, data-structures, loops

I need to extract data from a structure and put it into a list, but I don't know how many levels the structure has.

For each level, I can call `level.children()`, if there are no levels below the current one, it returns `[]`, if there are, it returns `[object, object, ...]`, on each of which I can call `children()` on again.

I need to drill down through the structure until I've extracted all levels of data into a list.

When based off a structure like this:

```
<name>John Smith</name>
<team link="http://teamwebsite.com">
    <name>Team Name</name>
</team>
<games>
    <location>
        <venue>A stadium</venue>
    </location>
</games>
```

The list should look something like this:

```
[
    [
        {'name': 'name', 'attrs': {}, 'text': 'John Smith', 'parent': None},
    ],
    [
        {'name': 'team', 'attrs': {'link': 'http://teamwebsite.com'}, 'text': '', 'parent': None},
        {'name': 'name', 'attrs': {}, 'text': 'Team Name', 'parent': 1}, # the reference to its parent's position in the list
    ],
    [
        {'name': 'games', 'attrs': {}, 'text': '', 'parent': None},
        {'name': 'location', 'attrs': {}, 'text': '', 'parent': 1},
        {'name': 'venue', 'attrs': {}, 'text': 'A stadium', 'parent': 2},
    ],
]
```

I'm trying to figure out the Python I would use to get from the data structure to my list. I need a kind of self-perpetuating for loop, but I can't come up with a good solution.

Anything to point me in the right direction? I'm sure there is some good theory for this kind of thing that I completely don't know about but would be happy to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're describing [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29), but I'm guessing there are [better](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), [ways](http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/topics/howto/xml-howto.html), [to](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm), [parse](http://www.diveintopython.org/xml_processing/), [XML](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonxml/chapter/ch01.html).

Comment: Is there? XML is a tree. Although if you had an XSD, you would know which nodes could have children and how many (even if "how many" was unbounded).

Comment: @Thomas Owens: By parsing it I mean not having to write the algorithm to parse it yourself...

Comment: Ah, a built-in iterator. How wonderful :p. Thanks for those links, I'll have a read of them all. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

The concept you're looking to use here is called "[Recursion](http://www.freenetpages.co.uk/hp/alan.gauld/tutrecur.htm)".